# Convert a .csv file to a .arff file using weka api in java

Tags: java, csv, exception, weka, arff

I am trying to convert a csv file to arff file using the code bellow :

```
public class Main{


        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


            // load CSV
            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
            loader.setSource(new File("file.csv"));
            Instances data = loader.getDataSet();//to get instance object

            // save ARFF
            ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
            saver.setInstances(data);
            saver.setFile(new File("file.arff"));
            saver.writeBatch();
        }
}
```

But this doesn't work well . it generates an exception  : "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bounce/net/DefaultAuthenticator"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bounce/net/DefaultAuthenticator
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.<clinit>(WekaPackageManager.java:99)
    at weka.core.Utils.readProperties(Utils.java:174)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.<init>(Capabilities.java:275)
    at weka.core.converters.AbstractSaver.getCapabilities(AbstractSaver.java:219)
    at weka.core.converters.ArffSaver.getCapabilities(ArffSaver.java:328)
    at weka.core.converters.AbstractSaver.setInstances(AbstractSaver.java:162)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bounce.net.DefaultAuthenticator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the NoClassDefFoundError @sali333?

Comment: Clearly from the stack trace it's at `saver.setInstances(data);`

Comment: @sali333 Please remove the screenshot and replace it with the stack trace data as text (formatted as code -- indent everything 4 spaces)

Comment: it is because of the  `setInstances `  line